# Pandas read_csv() parse multiple datetime formats

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parsing

I would like to read multiple data files that have different DateTime formats. But How can I parse these formats together in one go?

```
dateparse_1 = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f") 
dateparse_2 = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
dateparse_3 = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.")

for f in all_filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f,encoding='latin-1',low_memory=False, index_col='TimeStamp', parse_dates=True, date_parser = dateparse_1 or dateparse_2 or dateparse_3)
```

Comment: You can make a function which tries each of them in a row if there is an error. So nest your `try` and `except` calls.

Comment: thanks it's a good idea of solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `dateparse_{1,2,3}` by trying them until one succeeds.  For example,

```py
def combine_date_parsers(date_parsers):
    def combined_date_parser(value):
        for date_parser in date_parsers:
            try:
                return date_parser(value)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        else:
            raise ValueError(value)
    return combined_date_parser


dateparse_1 = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")
dateparse_2 = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
dateparse_3 = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.")

date_parser = combine_date_parsers([
    dateparse_1,
    dateparse_2,
    dateparse_3,
])

pd.read_csv(
    f,
    encoding='latin-1',
    low_memory=False,
    index_col='TimeStamp',
    parse_dates=True,
    date_parser=date_parser,
)
```